# android rxjava repeating a request

Tags: android, rx-java

I am trying to achieve the following. I load a list of objects I want to get values to put in a list later.

First I gather all the values into an array (to mountain order) using flatmap and then when everything is done I populate an adapter.

The thing I am unable to do is to repeat the operation ever xxx seconds. I understand its done using an interval. Still I get no result at all, or only none repeating one result.

Here’s my code:

```
  Observable.fromIterable(URLList)
            .concatMap(url -> standartRequest(App.getInstance().getApi().getService().getData(currency.getUrl())))
            .retry(Constants.RETRY_COUNT)
            .timeout(Constants.TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::success, this::error, this::valuesRetrieved); 



    recyclerView = ((CurrencyListFragment) controller).getRecyclerView();
    LinearLayoutManager linearManager = new LinearLayoutManager(controller.getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearManager);
}


private void valuesRetrieved() {
    listAdapter adapter = new listAdapter(valuesFromResponse);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void success(Object response) {
    valuesFromResponse.add(response);
}
```

Where do I put

```
.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).timeInterval()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well actually, you do not put `interval` anywhere, for repeating the operation every x interval, you should use `repeat` operator variant called `repeatWhen` where you can provide your interval logic in this way:

```
.repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

`repeatWhen()` will hand to you an `Observable` that transform your source `Observable` `onCompleted()` events as `onNext()` (with void), you should return `Observable` that emits `onNext()` which signals to resubscribe to your source `Observable` - meaning repeat the operation. While `onCompleted()/onError()` will be delivered as `onCompleted()/onError()` on your source `Observable`.
[recommended reading](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/) regarding `repeatWhen/retryWhen`.

One thing to consider, as `repeatWhen()` will basically swallows all your `onCompleted` events (as you're repeating the operation there is no `onCompleted()`, your `Observable` will not stop from by itself!), then you should gather and update the adapter differently, I guess you can simply use `toList()` to gather all items to single `onNext()` (a replacement to your `success()` logic) and then on each `onNext` updates the list (what you're doing on `onCompleted` right now), to sum it up:

```
 Observable.fromIterable(URLList)
            .concatMap(url -> standartRequest(App.getInstance().getApi().getService().getData(currency.getUrl())))
            .retry(Constants.RETRY_COUNT)
            .timeout(Constants.TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .toList()
            .repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::valuesRetrieved, this::error);
```

**EDIT:**

Your timeout and retry logic are applied to the entire operation chain, so if all the network requests together take more than `Constants.TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS` you will get timeout exception, you probably just want to retry and time out each individual request. like this:

```
Observable.fromIterable(URLList)
            .concatMap(url ->  standartRequest(App.getInstance()
                    .getApi().getService().getData(currency.getUrl())
                    .retry(Constants.RETRY_COUNT)
                    .timeout(Constants.TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))                
            .toList()
            .repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::valuesRetrieved, this::error);
```

Comment: Dear @yosriz, that code doesn't work because repeatWhen is triggered each time a query returns a result, making it retry all the queries from the start. Mb cose of the concatMap?

Comment: p.s. now I get a java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException :)

Comment: oh, that's because the retry and timeout, your'e time outing the entire operations (all the requests) so that's probably takes more than Constants.TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, you probably want this time out to each request not the whole operation

Comment: p.s. why your'e doing concat? don't you want parallelism?

Comment: I want to maintain item order in the list without sorting. concat does that.

Comment: Yes indeed, you can also use concatEager to have parallelism while maintaining items order

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that. 
I still cannot achieve a simple repeat( my guess is I am confusing the order of the operations. Getting basically the same result for an interval and repeat when (going into a loop that adds another loop which adds another loop, and so on and forth)

Comment: please accept the answer if that was helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**I am repeating my retrofit call every 2 second after it is completed**

```
//Retrofit Builder
        val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("http://worldtimeapi.org/")
            .build()

        val timeApi = retrofitBuilder.create(TimeApi::class.java)


    val timeObservable = timeApi.getTime()

    timeObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .repeatWhen { completed -> completed.delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
        .subscribe(object : Observer<Time> {
            override fun onComplete() {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "It is completed")
            }

            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "you have successfully subscribed ")
            }

            override fun onNext(t: Time) {
                progress.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                txtTime.text = t.unixtime
                Log.e("MainActivity", "OnNext Called" + t.unixtime)

            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "ERROR")
            }
        })

}
```

**See the Log Cat , onNext is called after every 2 second.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The repeatWhen can do the job, but in my sense, the interval could do the job as well, just like :

```
Observalbe.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .flatMap( /* Your Observabler.fromItere().concatMap().retry().timeout()*/)
  .subscribe{ /* refresh RecyclerView* / }
```

In this way, you use `flatMap` to switch one stream (interval) to another stream (your business logic).