# How to create repeatable network requests with RxJava?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I need my request to repeat once every 30 seconds. How can I force repeatWhen in this code?

```
override fun loadData() {
    disposable.add(
        weatherRepository.getCurrentLocation(activity)
            .flatMap { weatherRepository.getWeather(it.currentLocation).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                mView.showWeather()
                mView.setupWeather(it)
            }, {
                checkNetworkConnection()
                Log.d("Error", it.toString())
            })
            )
        }
```

Comment: Try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58815897/2462531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this before `subscribeOn` to repeat the same request:

```
.repeatWhen { completed -> completed.delay(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
```

So it will call the same request every 30 seconds of interval.

So your code becomes:

```
disposable.add(weatherRepository.getCurrentLocation(activity)
            .flatMap { weatherRepository.getWeather(it.currentLocation)
            .repeatWhen { completed -> completed.delay(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) }
    ....
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me!

Comment: Accept the answer if it helps :)